# Quiver algebras whose modules have a distributive submodule lattice

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Is there a classification (by quiver and relations) of finite dimensional quiver algebras such that every indecomposable right module has a distributive submodule lattice?